# Is it possible to have timeout for unit tests in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, timeout

I'd like each test to terminate with an error if it takes more than 1 second.

I'm using Facebook's Jest library, write the tests in JSX and run them from Gulp (this means they run on node.js).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but it clearly depends on your test framework. I am using mocha for example, which supports both [suite](http://mochajs.org/#suite-specific-timeouts) and [test-specific](http://mochajs.org/#test-specific-timeouts) timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes. It'd be as simple as:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Print tests that haven't run and clear queue
}, /* timeout here */);
```

But there's the situation where the event loop can be starved. For example:

```
(function foreverRun() {
  process.nextTick(foreverRun);
}());
```

To get around the above you'd need to hack Node's internals to force a brief interrupt during the processing of the `nextTickQueue` to check the state of testing.

For a strictly Node solution, the more sure way to do it is run the test script in a child process and kill it after the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

yes, just set the config in jest

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    testTimeout: 20000
}
```